# how can I debug exe with soem switch flags from command prompt

Tags: batch-file, debugging, command, prompt

for e.g from command prompt I need to launch the exe with some switch flags under debugger. How do I do it?

This is an exe from c/c++ and built using VS2005 environment that I need debug. I pass some flags to this exe to perform some stuff.

Comment: This, of course, depends on your debugger. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Which debugger do you want to launch?

Comment: *some -- Please proofread your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give more information about your development environment to get a specific answer.

For example, with a C# project in Visual Studio, you can right-click the project->Properties and then fill out the "Command line arguments" field in the "Debug" tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it worked. Right click on the project->Properties and then fill out the "Command line arguments" field in the "Debug" tab. bkane solution worked. thx.